# Can I lay peel and stick tiles over existing, old vinyl?

Tags: floor, vinyl

I am renting a place which has a very old and dirty vinyl flooring. Since I don't own that place, I don't want to spend a lot of money. The vinyl is in bith the kitchen and the entrance.

I have found [these peel and stick tiles](http://m.homedepot.com/p/TrafficMASTER-Bodden-Bay-12-in-x-12-in-Grey-Peel-and-Stick-Vinyl-Tile-30-sq-ft-case-26293061/206495383). Would that work, on top of this old, existing vinyl? They told me, at home depot, to apply another self stick tile primer.

Comment: Well at that price and it is a rental and may not last long but if you plan to stay for a few years clean the old vinyl and these tiles will serve you well, I have put similar down 15+ years ago and after deciding to sell the home called me to see if I could replace it. There were several tiles at the out door entrance that had shifted, I asked her if she still had the extras I gave her because I did not think they would last , they had been stored in the bottom of a pantry cabinet I pulled the tiles that had moved and put the extras down for just about 1.5 hours of work she was thrilled

Comment: RENTAL PROPERTY - Since this is a rental property you really should be taking this question up with the landlord. They may have some definite opinions about what you can and can not do to the property. And if the existing vinyl is as bad as you say it is it really should be up to the landlord to be changing the floor coverings.

Answer (score 1):

NO- Peel and stick vinyl is a trap! Glue-goop seeps up from the seams after about a year, making black blobs on the floor (to clean, scrub with a putty knife, weekly at least), while at the same time dirt begins to find its way under the edges of the tiles and then the corners begin to fail, peel up, and crack. If you get any dirt on the goop underneath the broken tile the floor, it's awful to try to get it off. You can peel the whole tile off, but you will never clean off the goop/glue, so you really can't take them off; and you can't add new/more vinyl on top of the peel and stick tiles either! Once you put peel and stick tiles down, there's no return. You'll have to pull up the first layer of vinyl and remove everything before you can add something else (because the peel and stick tiles will eventually peel up).

NIGHTMARE!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can think of in your situation is to put down really cheap floating laminate flooring.  This type of flooring is easy to install, and you don't have to worry about any glue.  When you leave, you don't have to explain to the landlord what you did to the floor, you can just pick up the floor and leave it like it was when you moved in.  You can buy this flooring at the big box stores for as little as $0.70 per square foot.  Wasted material, underlayment and tax may bring you up to $1.25

Comment: Look up groutable peel and stick. You install with spacing and then put down a special flexible grout to seal the gaps. It should completely prevent this for just a few bucks more and not much effort.